# JQuery - Reusable jqGrid creation function triggers the 'loadComplete' of the last table that used it

Tags: javascript, object, jqgrid, encapsulation

I created a reusable function for creating jqGrid.

```
function createJqGrid(){
    $("#" + gTableId).jqGrid({
            datastr: jsonData,
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function(obj) { return obj; }},
            headertitles: true,
            sortable: true,
            rownumbers: isRowNum,
            colNames: colHeadNames,
            colModel: colModel,
            rowNum: jsonData.length,
            width: viewableWidth,
            height: viewableHeight,     
            shrinkToFit: isShrink,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            onSelectRow: func,
            loadComplete: function(data) {
                alert(gTableId);                
            }
        });
}
```

This function and all the setting of parameters is encapsulated inside `MyObject`. My four jsp's have their own distinct instance of `MyObject`. But when I trigger a reloadGrid of jqGrid, the id of the last table that used this function is being alerted.

Given:
table1 is inside table1.jsp
table2 is inside table2.jsp
table3 is inside table3.jsp
table4 is inside table4.jsp

`$("#table1").trigger("reloadGrid");` alerts "table4"
`$("#table2").trigger("reloadGrid");` alerts "table4"
`$("#table3").trigger("reloadGrid");` alerts "table4"
`$("#table4").trigger("reloadGrid");` alerts "table4"


Seems like the `loadComplete` of the last created table is being triggered. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that the triggered `loadComplete` is the correct one and the issue is more with the logic of your JavaScript. The variables declaration section is missing in your sample but it looks like `gTableId` is a global variable. In that case every call to it will always get its last value (and your alert is always taking the current value of `gTableId`, it's not *freezed* in any way). Please try modifying your `loadComplete` like this to verify:

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
    alert($(this).attr('id');
}
```